# Magento 2.3 : Customer after login Storeview switcher/redirect problem

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, multistore, store-view, magento2.3.3

I have created 3 store for example:

1. Australia
2. India
3. USA

and created related store view as show below:
[image]

In my case if any customer is register from any store or store view. They are successfully register from any store/storeview. and successfully login from any store/storeview but after login from any store/storeview when user click on store/storeview switcher it's will not working.
In admin setting I have done

1. Add Store Code to Urls to Yes
2. Customer Share to "Globe"

Now problem is that I am able to login from any store/storeview but not able to switch from one store to another store after login, without login it's successfully working.

[image]

Anyone is able to help me for solve this issue.

[image]

Comment: Can you please check your URL after changing store and before it ?

Comment: I can see that before clicking on AU or IN, you have URL with base_url/magento2/ and in next image magento2 is missing I believe.

Comment: Yes, My URL is base_url/magento2/ but after login when customer switch to store  it's going to wrong url even without login it's working proper.

Comment: Hmmm, that's **ODD**

Comment: Let me check if I can able to find some solution for you then, will let you know after some research..

Comment: It's default magento2.3.3 nothing use any extension or any theme. it's default.

Comment: Okay will check and let you know. If I am able to generate same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After lot's of debug found that This issue in Magento 2.3.3 Default version.

In order to prevent this bug on 2.3.3, you need to update "`vendor\magento\module-store\etc` or override :

`magento2/app/code/Magento/Store/etc/di.xml` and comment to `hashGenerator` then the store switcher works for logged in customers.

**Before**

```
<type name="Magento\Store\Model\StoreSwitcher">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="storeSwitchers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="cleanTargetUrl" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\Model\StoreSwitcher\CleanTargetUrl</item>
                <item name="manageStoreCookie" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\Model\StoreSwitcher\ManageStoreCookie</item>
                <item name="managePrivateContent" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\Model\StoreSwitcher\ManagePrivateContent</item>
              <item name="hashGenerator" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\Model\StoreSwitcher\HashGenerator</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

**After:**

```
<type name="Magento\Store\Model\StoreSwitcher">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="storeSwitchers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="cleanTargetUrl" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\Model\StoreSwitcher\CleanTargetUrl</item>
                    <item name="manageStoreCookie" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\Model\StoreSwitcher\ManageStoreCookie</item>
                    <item name="managePrivateContent" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\Model\StoreSwitcher\ManagePrivateContent</item>
                    <!-- <item name="hashGenerator" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\Model\StoreSwitcher\HashGenerator</item> -->
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </type>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find more info about this issue here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/24942

To fix issue, you don't need to remove HashGenerator row in `vendor/magento/module-store/etc/di.xml`, just set `sortOrder="1000` for it, so it will look like:

```
        <argument name="storeSwitchers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="cleanTargetUrl" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\Model\StoreSwitcher\CleanTargetUrl</item>
            <item name="manageStoreCookie" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\Model\StoreSwitcher\ManageStoreCookie</item>
            <item name="managePrivateContent" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\Model\StoreSwitcher\ManagePrivateContent</item>
            <item name="hashGenerator" sortOrder="1000" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\Model\StoreSwitcher\HashGenerator</item>
        </argument>
```